# I want to extract multiple http cookies values for rewrite URL with the help of single regex expression

Tags: regex, cookies, url-rewriting, httpcookie

For input string1:

```
application_session=30110020;User_Context=Ghkkaskj228992nkn999
```

Possible regex for string1:

```
application_session=(.*);User_Context=(.*)
```

Where

```
{C:1} = 30110020
{C:2} = Ghkkaskj228992nkn999
```

For input string2:

```
User_Context=Ghkkaskj228992nkn999;application_session=30110020
```

Possible regex for string2:

```
User_Context=(.*);application_session=(.*)
```

Where

```
{C:1} =  Ghkkaskj228992nkn999
{C:2} =  30110020
```

And the solution fitting for both string1 and string2,

Possible regex:

```
User_Context=(.*);application_session=(.*)|application_session=(.*);User_Context=(.*)
```

Also, `C:1` and `C:2` are conditions references while rewriting the URL.

For references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

The above possibile regex has 2 expressions.

But we need **single regex expression**.

How can we do this?

Comment: Why do you want a single pattern? I am not sure if you can do that using capture groups with an alternation and then pointing to the same capture group value. With a regex that is done by using the same capture group name or a branch reset group, but I don't ECMAScript as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-syntax) allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Friend I'm not a regex pro but you could try

```
User_Context=(\w+);application_session=(\w+)|application_session=(\w+);User_Context=(\w+)
```

Lemme know if it works :)

Comment: Can you suggest some generic approach(i.e generalized regex) . What if we have 3 different cookies in the input string? This approach is getting all the combinations separated by OR operator, which i feel not reliable solution.
For Example: " application_session=30110020;User_Context=Ghkkaskj228992nkn999;Auth=99fjjmk89"